# Count related for multivalue lookup field

Tags: lookup-column

I've got two lists A and B.
List A has a **multivalue** lookup field that points to list B.

I want to create a field in list B that count the occurrences of each item in list A.

I'm using SharePoint 2013

Comment: Is this is what you are looking for: http://pawansatope.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-create-count-related-lookup.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have a this kind of field in Lookup list using SharePoint OOB features but, you can create a custom list view with custom Item Display template. In custom display template you need to write a logic to check the item usage in the target list and display the count in separate column in the List View.